# Eureka client: com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I'm using Eureka Server microservice and Eureka client microservice. I initialized the Eureka Server first, and then initialized the eureka client. I'm getting the following error!

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1069) [eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:983) [eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:430) [eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:276) [eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:272) [eureka-client-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:67) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:324) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:359) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:389) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:129) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf9c6c9.getEurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.sachintitus.jobpostingservice.JobpostingServiceApplication.main(JobpostingServiceApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
```

Properties file:

```
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.kidilanapp.cloud.model.jobposting")
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableFeignClients("com.sachintitus.jobpostingservice")
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class JobpostingServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JobpostingServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Eureka Server side:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class NetflixEurekaNamingServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NetflixEurekaNamingServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I've configured Eureka Server and Eureka client. When the Eureka client starts up, it throws the above mentioned error. Eureka server is running without any errors. What is going wrong?

**Edit**

POM file for client:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-feign -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloud-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

POM file for the server:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-services.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: can you post the main class where you have used the annotation and application.properties file content ?

Comment: @NirajJha Edited the post :)

Comment: is this the property on client-side?

Comment: This is client-side

Comment: @NirajJha Added server side too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FIX** 
Steps to fix the error:

1. Specify username and password for your Eureka Server in its properties file

   ```
   spring.security.basic.enabled=true
   spring.security.user.name=theusername
   spring.security.user.password=thepassword
   ```
2. Create Web Security Configuration for your Eureka Server

   ```
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
               .csrf()
               .disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
               .httpBasic();
      }
   }
   ```
3. Specify username and password in your Client properties file

> eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://theusername:thepassword@localhost:8761/eureka

**EXPLANATION** 
My Eureka Server requires username and password to authenticate, which means its endpoints are protected. Any request without valid credentials will obviously go through a 401 or 403. Please read the warnings above the stack trace (I forgot to add it to the question because I thought it's irrelevant. Sorry).

```
2020-03-03 19:56:07.716  WARN 13368 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure with status code 401; retrying on another server if available
```

The error disappears when you provide proper credentials

Comment: Great to know this, please don't forget to add everything.

Comment: Can you please tell us spring boot and spring cloud versions you have tried with? I have the same issue and the culprit is spring security. I have tried your solution but no difference. I have already looked at docs and github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2754. no difference. By the way my spring-boot version is: 2.5.2 and spring-cloud version is: 2020.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Remove `eureka.client.fetch-registry` property from client side as this property is used by eureka server to get the registry annotated with `@EnableDiscoveryClient`

Answer (score -1):

why this property added on the client-side?

```
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

this is added on server side.

Comment: shouldn't these be false on the server side?

Comment: it depends on generally marked false reason being we don't want the server itself to get registered.

Comment: can you show the pom file of server and client, sometimes version of cloud and dependency also cause an issue? better you set up the latest or stable version. Referring to some old blog can't help you just take the approach not copy everything.

Comment: Pom files are added

Comment: can you comment @EnableFeignClients and also share which spring-cloud.version is being used on the client and server-side?

Comment: Commenting out @EnableFeignClient did't make it any better. The version I'm running is Hoxton.SR1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208918/discussion-between-niraj-jha-and-sachin-titus).